# Jquery Autocomplete Selected value split in two text boxes

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am looking for functionality that would split selected items from a jQuery Autocomplete dropdown in two different text boxes.

So far I tried the following which isn't working:

```
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    var param = { LocKeyword: $('[id*=txtCity]').val() };
    $.ajax({
      url: "/UPSLocator.aspx/GetQueryData",
      data: JSON.stringify(param),
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataFilter: function (data) {
        return data;
      },
      success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
          return {
            value: item
          }
        }))
      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message)
        // console.log("Ajax Error!");  
      }
    });
  },
  select: function (event, ui) {
    var SelectedVal = ui.item.value;

    alert(SelectedVal);
    debugger;
    var array = SelectedVal.split(',')
    $('[id*=txtCity]').val(array[0]);
    $('[id*=txtState]').val(array[1]);
  },
  minLength: 6 //This is the Char length of inputTextBox  
});
```

I am only getting following response from the above snippet.

```
{city, state}
```

I am able to set the value for `state` but city textbox is set as city,state it's not splitting.

Comment: can you post data returned from ajax?

Comment: Yes I am sending search text to backend code and fetched the data from service. I am able to fetch the data as per required. But not able to split fetched data between two different textboxes. at select: i am spliting data, but again it reset to first textbox its shows combination of city and state instead of city only.

Comment: Understood, you could send an example of the data returned  {city, state} for me to create a fiddle, If you put the html too would be nice.

Comment: Here is my data in used js for reference.
var data =[{New York,New York},
{Los Angeles,California},
{Chicago,Illinois},
{Houston,Texas},
{Phoenix,Arizona},
{Philadelphia,Pennsylvania},
{San Antonio,Texas},
{San Diego,California},
{Dallas,Texas},
{San Jose,California},
{Austin,Texas},
{Jacksonville,Florida},
{San Francisco,California}];

 <input type="text" class="autocomplete" name="fruits" id="txtCity" /> 
  State <input type="text" name="fruits" id="txtState" />

Due to limitation i have added only html textbox js function is already shared in earliar request.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to manipulate the data?

The `autocomplete` widget expects an array of JSON objects with `label` and `value` properties (although if you just specify `value`, it will be used as the label). So in the simplest case, you can just return data that looks like this:

```
[
    { state: 'Texas', city: 'San Antonio' }, 
    { state: 'Texas', city: 'Dallas' },
    { state: 'Texas', city: 'Austin' }
]

select: function( event, ui ) {
   $("#txtState").val(ui.item.state);       
   $("#txtCity").val(ui.item.city);
}
```

There is a example with another data:

https://jsfiddle.net/dabc61ma/1/

Comment: @Mike McCaughan Thanks for supporting so long. I am trying to populate data as per your suggestion. But it still working as earliar. like i am able to load value in city textbox as it is coming from response. not spliting in two textboxes. 

Like as your fiddle example "Little ,Grebe" this is my selected value which is displayed as it is "Little ,Grebe" in city textbox. not splilting as expected city textbox filled with Little and state textbox with Grebe.

Just want to know it is feasible.

Comment: Thanks for supporting so long. I found that the select event runs before the autocomplete actually sets the value of the input, so whenevent handler sets the value, it's almost immediately overwritten.
So set below code. 
 select: function (e, i) {
    setTimeout(function () {var SelectVal = i.item.value;var array = SelectVal.split(',')$('[id*=txtCity]').val(array[0]);$('[id*=txtState]').val(array[1]);
                        }, 0);
                    },

Now its working as expected.